# Task Serialization error at the line "df.show()"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11. I have this piece of code and I get Task Serialization error at the line `df.show()`. However, when I substitute `df.show()` by `df.count()`, then it runs well and shows the number of rows in the DataFrame:

```
def detection(z: Double, p: Double): String = {
  var value : String = "-"
  if (z < 1) { 
    if (p < 1) value = "A"
    else value = "B"
  }
  else {
    if (p < 1) value = "C"
    else value = "D"
  }
  value
}

val detectionUdf = udf(detection _)

df = df.withColumn("det",detectionUdf(df("col1"), df("col2")))

df.show()
```

Comment: Off topic: Instead of a mutable `value` you can use `return` everywhere you're assigning it a value, no?

Comment: @philantrovert: How does it influence on the task serialization? Could you please explain? For example, I can run `df.coalesce(1).write.option("sep",";").option("header","true").csv(outputdir + "/test.csv")`

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't. Maybe I should've marked **Off-topic** in bold.

Comment: @philantrovert: Well, after adding `return` to the function `detection`, the error of Task Serialization has disappeared. So, it had some impact, no?

Comment: I'm not sure why. I just added that comment because mutable variables are not preferred. You don't need to explicitly return as well. You can use `if (p >1 ) "C" else "D" `

Comment: So, it was the solution of my problem:)